# My core data fetch is not recognizing context

Tags: swift, core-data, fetch, nsmanagedobject

In my swift code below I am trying to fetch all of my names in core data to print. I am getting a compile error on context saying it can't be found in scope. I have attached a photo as well so you can see what is in my core data.

```
@objc func pressRight(){
 
    var locations  = [Place]() // Where Locations = your NSManaged Class

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "name")
    locations = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Place]

    // Then you can use your properties.

    for location in locations {

      print(location.name)

    }

   
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: So how can we help you with this? You need to make sure you have access to an instance of NSManagedObjectContext somehow but without knowing more about your code it’s hard to say how. Also you have no entity named “name”.

Comment: Where is `context` declared? Where did you copy the code from?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Core Data problem, it's a Swift problem. All variables and properties in Swift have to be declared before you can use them. For example you can't just write

```
i = 5
```

Unless somewhere you already have something like

```
var i: Int
```

In your code you're using something called `context` that was never declared. Swift doesn't know what it is, which is what it's telling you.

Since you're using Core Data it looks like you want `context` to be an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`. If your app already has an `NSPersistentContainer` somewhere, you can get a context from it, using either `viewContext` or `newBackgroundContext` (which one depends on exactly how you're using it; here it's probably `viewContext`).

If you don't already have an `NSPersistentContainer` somewhere in your app, you may want to read up a little on how to use Core Data. You can't just declare the context; it needs to be configured correctly with the container before use.